# ASP.NET Core Health checks in multi tenant environment using routing configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, health-monitoring

I started using Health checks from Asp.net Core, I love them but I could not find an easy way to wire it up with tenant based routing, for example supporting:

- /health [generic non tenant specific checks]
- /{tenant}/health [tenant specific check]

If I succeeded with this approach I could have used tags to filter which health check to use, but unfortunately I failed to configure the routing for the request.

```
app.UseEndpointRouting();
app.UseHealthChecks("/{tenant}/health", new HealthCheckOptions
    {
        ResponseWriter = WriteCustomHealthResponse,
        AllowCachingResponses = false,
        Predicate = _ => _.Tags.Contains("tenant-specific")
    });
```

The above code is not routing correctly.
I explored the possibility to use something like the below:

```
app.MapWhen(context => 
    context.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get.Method &&
    context.Request.?ROUTEDATA?.SOMECHECK("/{tenant}/HealthCheck"),
                builder => builder.UseHealthChecks());
```

But in this case I don't have a way to check if the routing is correct.

Comment: Why would you need this? The health check is for the application as a whole.

Comment: Well I disagree, in my architecture I can have availability issues affectign only certain tenants, also I have tenant specific databases for example, and various tenant driven configurations, integrations and so on. I want to check multi tenant resources (and more) but also tenant specific, which I don't know necessarily if they exist. Maybe I am overloading the feature but this really give me a nice insight about the system status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the solution I found is to use query string parameters and use the `IHttpContextAccessor` to search for the tenant parameter.
For this purpose I created a base abstract implementation of `IHealthCheck`.

```
public abstract class BaseTenantHealthCheck : IHealthCheck
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public BaseTenantHealthCheck(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected string GetTenant()
    {
        return _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request?.Query["tenant"].ToString();
    }

    protected bool IsTenantSpecificCheck() => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetTenant());

    public abstract Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
}
```

Within the implementation class then I pass the context accessor shown below.

```
public class MylAvailabilityHealthCheck : BaseTenantHealthCheck
{
    public MyAvailabilityHealthCheck(IOptionsMonitor<MyAvailabilityCheckOptions> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    : base(httpContextAccessor)
    {
        [..]
```

To access the health check I use:

- `http://{url}/health` [for multi tenant checks]
- `http://{url}/health?tenant=TenantName` [for tenant specific checks]

I look forward to hear if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: [here](https://medium.com/asos-techblog/implementing-net-core-2-2-health-checks-7f813fd71772) you have a good article about healthchecks implementations

Comment: @Norcino - Assuming Asp.Net Core 3.0 (might need to be 3.1) - you can resolve path parameters with Endpoint Routing in your Health Check. You would need to inject the HttpContextAccessor into the health check and pull the RouteData object from the context.
`//In Health Check
var routeData = _accessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData();
var databaseName = routeData.Values["nameOfPathParameter"].ToString();
//Startup.cs - ConfigureServices
            registry
                .AddHealthChecks()
                .AddTypeActivatedCheck<SqlServerHealthCheck>("mssql", HealthStatus.Degraded);`

Comment: Rest of the Code:
`app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
     endpoints.MapControllers();
     endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/api/health-check/db/mssql/{nameOfPathParameter}", new HealthCheckOptions
                {
                    Predicate = SqlServerHealthCheckPredicate
                });
            });

        public static Func<HealthCheckRegistration, bool> SqlServerHealthCheckPredicate =
            registration => registration.Name.Equals("mssql", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
`

Comment: Thanks JGx714791, I will try the different mapping you are proposing